# Clip Getting Cut Short on Export with Adobe Audition

Tags: missing, short

I have a simple UI double-beep from Freesound: https://freesound.org/people/GokhanBiyik/sounds/351209/ and am attempting to reverse it for a programming project.

I drop it in a blank Audition, and do `Effects > Reverse`. The file sounds exactly as wanted.

Then go to `Export > File`. The resulting file has only one beep.

Does this happen to everyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your playback software (player, game engine) doesn't have a fadeout? That is a really short sound, so you might want to look into settings.

Also, have you tried to open the reversed file in audition after export? Is it cut off or full?

So:

1. if its full -> check your playback settings
2. if its short -> use any other free software like Audacity to reverse

Comment: Embarrassingly you are right, it was the player and not Audition itself that cut the sound short. I imported the sound that had been flipped from Audition back into Audition, and it was complete, so it works for my project.